# How to draw different line segment with different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about using geom_segment in R ggplot2.

For example, I have three facets and two clusters of points(points which have the same y values) in each facets, how do I draw multiple vertical line segments for each clustering with geom_segment?

Like if my data is

```
x <- (1:24)                   
y <- (rep(1,2),2,rep(2,2),1,rep(3,2),4, rep(4,1),5,6, ..rep(8,2),7)
facets <-(1,2,3) 
factors <-(1,2,3,4,5,6)                  
xmean <- ( (1+2+3)/3, (4+5+6)/3, ..., (22+23+24)/3)
```

Note: (1+2+3)/3 is the mean first cluster in the first facet and (4+5+6)/3 is the mean second cluster in the second facet and (7+8+9)/3 is the first cluster in the **second** facet.

My Code:

```
ggplot(,aes(x=as.numeric(x),y=as.numeric(y),color=factors)+geom_point(alpha=0.85,size=1.85)+facet_grid(~facets)

+geom_segment(what should I put here to draw this line in different factors?)
```

Desired result:
[image: Pictures (the plot that I want)]

Please see the picture!

Please see the updated picture!

[image: Updated Picture]

Thank you so much! Have a nice day :).

Comment: I try various plotting codes with geom_segment, but none of them work appropriately. Drawing lines in all facets or not showing things or errors.

Comment: Would you mind making your code runnable? If the question is about the segments, can you format your code such that we can run it and get a plot up to the point of segments?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Instead of working with vectors put your data in a dataframe. Doing so you could easily make an aggregated dataframe with the mean  values per facet and cluster which makes it easy to the segments:

Note: Wasn't sure about the setup of your data. You talk about two clusters per facet but your data has 8. So I slightly changed the example data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:24,
  y = rep(1:6, each = 4),
  facets = rep(1:3, each = 8)
)

df_sum <- df %>%
  group_by(facets, y) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'facets'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = factor(y))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.85, size = 1.85) +
  geom_segment(data = df_sum, aes(x = x, xend = x, y = y - .25, yend = y + .25), color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~facets)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Stefan. Thank you so much for helping with this plotting problem.  I actually my real data set has factors,  which means for the data point on a row, they do not belong to the same factor.  For example, the 4 Orange points in the first factors could belong to 3 different factors. (Like factor1, factor2, factor3) and same for other clusters. How could I deal with this? Since I notice the way you created df_sum is assume all the factors belong to the same factors and have the same numbers of points.

Comment: Hi @hskdhs. Could you please update your example data? I don't understand what you mean by the "4 Orange points could belong to 3 different factors". Actually your example data and my "interpretation" of your data does not make use of any factors except when mapping y on color.

Comment: Hi, Stefan. I have updated my example picture and dataset. I think the only difference is, for each cluster, they do not have the same y values.

Comment: No worries! I have desired result, thank you Stefan!